# Extending meteor user model

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to add an additional field to the users collection.

I have the correct `update` permissions set.

```
//called in my template event handler for a form post
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { company: company._id }});
```

However, whenever I access Meteor.user(), I don't see the company field?

I've tried setting up a pub/sub, but I'm still not having any luck retrieving the field.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It turned out that the value being passed over to the new field was undefined. Once I corrected that, landlands answer worked perfectly.

Comment: For fields that a user can always modify, its simplest to use Meteor's built-in support via the profile field as David Weldon suggests.  The profile field is automatically published for the logged-in user and it is automatically user-editable.  No additional pub/subs required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set permissions to allow user updates outside of profile fields.

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function(userId, doc){
        return doc._id === userId; // can update their own profile
    }
});
```

Then set publishing of the company field

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                           {fields: {'company': 1}});
});
```

and subscribe

```
Meteor.subscribe('userData');
```

Answer (score 5):

By default you can only update your profile (not arbitrary fields) from the client. So you could do:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {$set: {'profile.company': company._id }});
```

which may be what you want to do anyway. For more information about allow/deny rules and publishing user fields to the client, have a careful read of the [users section](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) of the docs.

Comment: Is this still the case, one can only update the users collection under the profile object?

Comment: You can update any fields on user, but by default you can only update the profile on the client. I suspect this will change over time because it's a somewhat strange and arbitrary rule with security consequences. See the first section of my post on [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for more details.

Comment: I got bitten by this the other day.  I tried to add another field to the user collection and couldn't.  So I ended up adding the field under user.profile and it worked fine.  Now everything goes under profile, but for some reason it just didn't 'feel' right to me.  Thanks.

Comment: You can add one via a method call, but you'll need to publish it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571451/publishing-custom-meteor-user-fields).