# Publishing custom Meteor.user() fields

Tags: meteor

I know this question has been asked numerous times but I am having a difficult time publishing this information.

In Accounts.onCreateUser I am adding a field like so

```
{
 ...
 user['info'] = { email: options.email, is_admin: false};
}
```

I publish this information;

```
Meteor.publish('user', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { info: 1} });
}
```

and

```
Meteor.subscribe('user');
```

After debugging the Publish query returns the correct information but that is never given to the client when I try to access Meteor.user(). Do I have to do something else to allow info to be access by Meteor.user()?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll want to use null to publish to the single user.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {info: 1}});
});
```

Comment: Please excuse my meteor newbyness but can you explain or provide any doc or tutorial reference for using null as the publish name?  Is a subscribe necessary or would the values now be automatically visible in the current user object? Thanks!

Comment: No subscription is necessary - publish null means 'autopublish' (not to be confused with the Meteor package called autopublish). http://support.kadira.io/knowledgebase/articles/379961-what-is-null-autopublish-publication

Comment: Above link is now 404. Link to cached view: https://web.archive.org/web/20170510202024/http://support.kadira.io/knowledgebase/articles/379961-what-is-null-autopublish-publication