# Meteor - Method adding user custom field do not work

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods

I am trying to add a custom "isContributor" field through a method to Meteor.Users but somehow it is not adding the field. (I am talking even before any safety check of who can do this update).

On client side I have the following event:

```
Template.Articles.events({
'click #BeContributor': function() {
    userId = Meteor.userId();
    Meteor.call('setContributorState', userId);
}
```

});

and in server/main.js the following:

```
Meteor.methods({
    setContributorState: function(userId) {
        Meteor.users.update(userId, {
          $set: {
                isContributor: true
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Somehow it does not add the field for my user. No console or server errors. I guess I missed something in term of right to add-up the field. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

--- EDIT ---

Actually the method was working but I did not publish back the result so I could not check in MeteorToys that the field was updated. With the following publication it works:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {isContributor: 1}});
});
```

found at [Publishing custom Meteor.user() fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571451/publishing-custom-meteor-user-fields)

Comment: try `console.log` in your server method to check whether it's really being called or not.

Comment: Just checked: method is called and UserId is properly being carried out until then. The update does not seem to be working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to modify the logged-in user's contributor status, you do not need to pass any parameter. This is a security hole. Server has the information who is calling the request.

```
Meteor.methods({
setContributorState: function() {
    Meteor.users.update({_id:this.userId}, {
      $set: {
            isContributor: true
            }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the safety clarification.